# 3D graphic / plot / visualization

Tags: wolfram-alpha

Could someone tell me how to get *WolframAlpha* to graph/plot/show graphic of this:

```
16<=x^2+y^2+z^2<=25 ; x,=0
```

This did not work:

```
3dplot[x^2+y^2+z^2]
```

Comment: This site is really for Mathematica questions. In Mathematica, I think you can use `RegionPlot3D`, like this: `expr = x^2 + y^2 + z^2; RegionPlot3D[
 16 <= x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 25, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}]` screen shot: ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6e3v6.png)  (I do not know what `x=0` means in your input.

Comment: You might also want post this on community.wolfram.com.

Comment: But if you do it and get an answer there, please post it here also.

Answer (score 1):

```
Manipulate[
 RegionPlot3D[
  16 <= x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 25,
  {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}, {x, -5, xs},
  PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}, {-5, 5}},
  AxesLabel -> Automatic],
 {{xs, 0, "x Cross Section"}, -4.5, 5, 0.5,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]

Manipulate[
 RegionPlot[
  16 <= x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 25,
  {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5},
  PlotRange -> {{-5.5, 5.5}, {-5.5, 5.5}},
  FrameLabel -> Automatic],
 {{x, 0, "x Cross Section"}, -4.5, 4.5, .5,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

I could only get a 2D plot out of WolframAlpha

```
WolframAlpha[
 "plot 16 <= x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 25 with 
 x = 0, y = -5 to 5, z = -5 to 5"]
```